# pandas dealing with a column with multiple values separated with delimiter for data analysis

Tags: pandas

here's a python self learner trying to find a way working with columns with multiple values. the dataset is TMDb Movie Dataset and there are multiple values columns are like genres, cast etc.

I managed splitting values and counting them, it's okay. but what if I want to see the relationship between genres and for example popularity? how can I group all genres after a proper splitting process?

[dataset looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFsSa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like the [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) function to create a row for every item when splitting. For example, when you want to group by genre, create a row for genre when splitting (keeping other columns the same). With that you can do simple groupby operations.

Comment: thank you so much!when I search .stack() for further information I've found a solution of my problem just like you mentioned. here it is for other pals:  https://link.medium.com/Oi0lAkLfI5